# convert GMT to Newzealand time

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

How to convert GMT date to Newzealand date time format in Oracle 11G.

```
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE('date','DD-MM-YY HH: MI: SS')+13/24,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24: MI: SS')
```

But, this will not work as during daylight saving its OK, but during normal days I need to make it +12.

Is there any Oracle function for the same?

Comment: So, is `date` a column in your table, and it is in `varchar2` format, but it is meant to represent a date-time in DD-MM-YY HH:MI:SS format? (Note that there is no HH:MI:SS, it must be either HH24:MI:SS or HH:MI:SS AM). If so, WHY? Why is it not in `date` data type? Then: Oracle has `timestamp with timezone` data type, which can be used for these conversions.

Comment: What is the data type of the column??

Answer (score 0):

It depends on data type of your date column.

- Case `TIMESTAMP WITH LOCAL TIME ZONE`

  Change your session time zone with `ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'NZ';` before you run the query.
- Case `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`

  Run `SELECT date_col AT TIME ZONE 'NZ' FROM ...`
- Case `TIMESTAMP`

  Run `SELECT FROM_TZ(date_col, 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'NZ' FROM ...`
- Case `DATE`

  Run `SELECT FROM_TZ(CAST(date_col AS TIMESTAMP), 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'NZ' FROM ...`
- Case `VARCHAR2`

  This would be a very poor design. Change the data type to one of the types above (preferably `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`). As a workaround use `SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(date_col||' UTC', 'DD-MM-YY HH24: MI: SS TZR') AT TIME ZONE 'NZ' FROM ...`

Note, in your question you use date format `DD-MM-YY HH: MI: SS`, is that correct? `HH` means hour in 12-hour format, this is ambiguous in case of missing `AM/PM` indicator. Also year should be always provided by four digits.

Comment: How can I use ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = 'NZ'; in my procedure?

Comment: `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = ''NZ''';`

Comment: Is this a valid one  alter session set nls_date_format='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Comment: Yes, of course. In PL/SQL you can also use `DBMS_SESSION.SET_NLS('NLS_DATE_FORMAT', '"DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS"');`

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8bff/3)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dates ( dt ) As
-- London on British Summer Time, NZ on winter time
SELECT DATE '2017-09-23' + INTERVAL '3' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- London on British Summer Time, NZ on Daylight Savings Time
SELECT DATE '2017-09-24' + INTERVAL '3' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- London on British Summer Time, NZ on Daylight Savings Time
SELECT DATE '2017-10-25' + INTERVAL '3' HOUR FROM DUAL UNION ALL
-- London on Daylight Savings Time, NZ on Daylight Savings Time
SELECT DATE '2017-10-29' + INTERVAL '3' HOUR FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

If your times are stored as local London times (respecting BST/DST):

```
SELECT dt AS London_time,
       CAST(
         FROM_TZ(
           CAST( dt AS TIMESTAMP ),
           'Europe/London'
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific/Auckland'
         AS DATE
       )
       AS Auckland_Time
FROM   dates
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8bff/3/0)**:

```
|          LONDON_TIME |        AUCKLAND_TIME |
|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2017-09-23T03:00:00Z | 2017-09-23T14:00:00Z |
| 2017-09-24T03:00:00Z | 2017-09-24T15:00:00Z |
| 2017-10-25T03:00:00Z | 2017-10-25T15:00:00Z |
| 2017-10-29T03:00:00Z | 2017-10-29T16:00:00Z |
```

**Query 2**:

If your times are stored as UTC:

```
SELECT dt AS London_time,
       CAST(
         FROM_TZ(
           CAST( dt AS TIMESTAMP ),
           'UTC'
         ) AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific/Auckland'
         AS DATE
       )
       AS Auckland_Time
FROM   dates
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d8bff/3/1)**:

```
|          LONDON_TIME |        AUCKLAND_TIME |
|----------------------|----------------------|
| 2017-09-23T03:00:00Z | 2017-09-23T15:00:00Z |
| 2017-09-24T03:00:00Z | 2017-09-24T16:00:00Z |
| 2017-10-25T03:00:00Z | 2017-10-25T16:00:00Z |
| 2017-10-29T03:00:00Z | 2017-10-29T16:00:00Z |
```

*(Note: you can remove the outer `CAST( .. AS DATE )` if you want the value as a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type.)*